# CSS counter with specific count at the start

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to start a counter from specific number along with the inner counter with specific count.

something like this :

```
2 
  2.3
  2.4
  2.5
3
4
```

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}
ol li:before {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  content: counter(mycounter) ". ";
}
ol:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: mycounter;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 2
    <ol>
      <li>Item 2.3 </li>
      <li>Item 2.4</li>
       <li>Item 2.5</li>
      <li>Item  2.6</li>
       <li>Item 2.7</li>
      <li>Item  2.8</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset

Comment: Just by typing your questions title on google gives you plenty of answers

Comment: @VilleKoo Yes you are right. But the answers doesn't give me to reset the counter and start from middle numbers. If you know the answer please comment else ignore.

Comment: Did you even check the link @CBroe provided you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below solution

> More help on CSS Counters [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.main {
  counter-reset: section 1;
}

.submain {
  counter-reset: subsection 2;
}

.submain1 {
  counter-reset: subsection 3;
}

ol.main>li {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

ol li:before {
  color: red;
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}

ol li li:before {
  color: red;
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol class="main">
  <li>Item 2
    <ol class="submain">
      <li>Item 2.3 </li>
      <li>Item 2.4</li>
      <li>Item 2.5</li>
      <li>Item 2.6</li>
      <li>Item 2.7</li>
      <li>Item 2.8</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>Item 3
    <ol class="submain1">
      <li>Item 3.4 </li>
      <li>Item 3.5</li>
      <li>Item 3.6</li>
      <li>Item 3.7</li>
      <li>Item 3.8</li>
      <li>Item 3.9</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

Find Below solution.

```css
 ol { counter-reset: item }
        li { display: block }
        li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<ol>
        <li>Item 1
            <ol>
                <li>Item 1.1 
                    <ol>
                        <li>Item 1.1.1 </li>
                        <li>Item 1.1.2</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Item 1.2</li>
                <li>Item 1.3</li>
                <li>Item 1.4</li>
                <li>Item 1.5</li>
                <li>Item 1.6</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
```

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}
ol li:before {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  content: counter(mycounter) ". ";
}
ol:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: mycounter;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 2
    <ol>
      <li>Item 2.3 </li>
      <li>Item 2.4</li>
       <li>Item 2.5</li>
      <li>Item  2.6</li>
       <li>Item 2.7</li>
      <li>Item  2.8</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: ol { counter-reset: item +1 }